# List directories on a server

Tags: shell, web

I have a directory on a server. I need to find the list of sub directories and find the latest one.

How do I accomplish this using shell script ?

Comment: What do you mean by "on a webserver"?

Comment: This question is too vague, please elaborate and I'll remove the downvote and improve my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have *local* access then `ls -adt */. | head -n 1` should work.

If you don't have local access, the best way to get something like `wget <url>/?C=M;O=D -q -O -` and parse the results - if the Web server is Apache and `Indexes` directive is on for the directory.

Comment: I know that we can download files using wget. But how do I list ?

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answered per se, please __edit__ the question and explain a bit.

Comment: an sample directory listing would be nice, for starters

Comment: http://nexus.server.com:8001/nexus/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/com/sample/directory


I need to find the list of directories in this URL. And find the last modified one.

Comment: Your command 'wget <url>/?C=M;O=D -q -O' is creating an index.html page. Is there any way that it gives me the output in console itself ?

Comment: that's what the last `-` is for

Comment: Shell is prompting this when I enter the command everytime. And even with the last '-', the output is stored in the html only and not visible in console

CORRECT>wget http://maven.apache.org/?C=M ; OLD -q -o - (y|n|e|a)? no

Comment: Its working after I removed 'O=D' in ****?C=M;O=D****. Thanks !